# Regex global without collection c#

Tags: c#, regex

How can I get global Regex in one string, and not in collection

```
Regex r = new Regex(".+");
Match match = r.Match("aaaa \r\n bbbb");
string result=match.Value;
```

I get: `result="aaaa "` and I want: `result="aaaa \r\n bbbb"`
I know that I can get that in a collection, but I need get that in `Match` datatype rather.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.` doesn't match linebreaks unless you make it to.

You can use `(?s)` for that, like: `new Regex("(?s).+")`

Or the `Singleline` option, like: `new Regex(".+", RegexOptions.Singleline)`

Answer (score 2):

The dot does not match newline characters by default, so you need to compile the regex using the `RegexOptions.Singleline` flag:

```
Regex r = new Regex(".+", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```